# PHP DOMDocument + Templates

Tags: php, php-5.6

I seem to have a problem loading perfectly valid HTML into the PHP DOMDocumnent. Some research suggests this is related to libxml poorly handling the content within script tags. However I've not been able to find a good way around this.

I've created a simplified test case below:

Source:

```
<?php

$testData = "
<p>Foo bar &reg;</p>

<script id='tmpl-js' type='text/x-jsrender'>
    <div>
        {{for items}}
            <div>
                {{ tmpl='#item-tmpl-js'/}}
            </div>
        {{/for}}
    </div>
</script>

<script id='item-tmpl-js' type='text/x-jsrender'>
    <div>
        {{title}}
    </div>
</script>
";

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($testData, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
```

Output:

```
WARNING DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Unexpected end tag : div in Entity, line: 9 on line number 25

WARNING DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Unexpected end tag : div in Entity, line: 11 on line number 25

WARNING DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Unexpected end tag : div in Entity, line: 17 on line number 25
```

Has anyone figured out a way to get around this?
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9c658439fe277c0f99e1fb823150a4d14d03a693

Comment: Have you tried loadXML instead? I tried that, and by adding a surrounding div tag, I was able to see the HTML in your example.

Comment: Remove one issue and another comes up. We also have HTML encoded entities in the content.
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7d4890b0bfe753168b2de46e9bc7bb4f55632086

Comment: Try a replace on & with %20. In your sandbox, that seemed to take care of it. After loading, you can replace it in reverse.

Comment: Do you need the templates loaded into your document or you want them ignored?

Comment: @SloanThrasher that did it! You should've added it an an answer so I can accept it

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález essentially I need to do some reformatting of some rendered Drupal content, the tpl.php file contains a couple of small JS templates and I needed a way to reformat the rendered output

Comment: @Hawxby Well, I'm not fully sure of what that means, but you since cannot manipulate those templates from plain DOMDocument anyway, I've added an answer.

Comment: @Hawxby, I've added it as an answer....

Answer (score 0):

DOMDocument is not a full-fledged browser, it's only a DOM parser. As such, the only thing you can do is probably to generate simple HTML that doesn't require support for the `<script>` tag and at least get the JavaScript templates ignored:

```
$testData = "
<p>Foo bar &reg;</p>

<script id='tmpl-js' type='text/x-jsrender'><!--
    <div>
        {{for items}}
            <div>
                {{ tmpl='#item-tmpl-js'/}}
            </div>
        {{/for}}
    </div>
--></script>

<script id='item-tmpl-js' type='text/x-jsrender'><!--
    <div>
        {{title}}
    </div>
--></script>
";
```

<sup>I hear the "do not wrap script tags in HTML comments any more" mantra every time, allegedly because "all browsers nowadays support JavaScript". As your use case illustrates, it's at most a half true.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php

$testData = "
<p>Foo bar &reg;</p>

<script id='tmpl-js' type='text/x-jsrender'>
    <div>
        {{for items}}
            <div>
                {{ tmpl='#item-tmpl-js'/}}
            </div>
        {{/for}}
    </div>
</script>

<script id='item-tmpl-js' type='text/x-jsrender'>
    <div>
        {{title}}
    </div>
</script>
";

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$testData = '<div>' . str_replace('&','%20',$testData) . "</div>";
$dom->loadHTML($testData, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
```